# What is the best data model for a DynamoDB table which holds git commits?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for the most appropriate table structure for a DynamoDB
table that will hold (git) commits by repository.

There are two equally popular requests in the system:

1. Put a commit by `unique(repository + sha)` [reject if not unique]
2. Get a specific commit by `repository + sha`
3. Get first `n` commits by a repository in ascending / descending order

---

I've tried creating a table with a KeySchema that has `hash: repository, range: sha`
and a secondary index with `hash: repository, range: createdAt, projection: ALL`

This has the advantage of being able to atomically reject a commit
if it has the same repository + sha as another commit (via ConditionExpression).
It also has the disadvantage of requiring 2x the size (as I need to be able to project
all keys for the 3rd query).

Is there a way to support the three queries above without the 2x size requirement.

---

Here's the code, to clarify:

```js
async function createCommitsTable() {
  await dyn.createTable({
    ProvisionedThroughput,
    TableName: COMMITS,
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      {AttributeName: 'repository', AttributeType: 'S'},
      {AttributeName: 'sha', AttributeType: 'S'},
      {AttributeName: 'createdAt', AttributeType: 'N'},
    ],
    KeySchema: [
      {AttributeName: 'repository', KeyType: 'HASH'},
      {AttributeName: 'sha', KeyType: 'RANGE'},
    ],
    LocalSecondaryIndexes: [{
      IndexName: 'CreatedAtIndex',
      Projection: {ProjectionType: 'ALL'},
      KeySchema: [
        {AttributeName: 'repository', KeyType: 'HASH'},
        {AttributeName: 'createdAt', KeyType: 'RANGE'},
      ]
    }]
  })
}
```

Put a commit into a table:

```js
async function putCommits() {
  await dc.put({
    TableName: COMMITS,
    Item: {
      repository: 'linux',
      sha: '6a13feb9c82803e2b815eca72fa7a9f5561d7861',
      createdAt: Date.now()
    },
    ConditionExpression:
      'attribute_not_exists(repository) and attribute_not_exists(sha)'
  })
}
```

Query the table for a single and for many commits (sorted by `createdAt`):

```js
async function queryCommits() {
  console.log('[single commit]:\n', await dc.get({
    TableName: COMMITS,
    Key: {
      repository: 'linux',
      sha: '6a13feb9c82803e2b815eca72fa7a9f5561d7861'
    }
  }));

  console.log('[commits by repo]:\n', await dc.query({
    TableName: COMMITS,
    IndexName: 'CreatedAtIndex',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'repository = :repository',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':repository': 'linux'
    }
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a composite key of createdAt and sha like this:

```
async function createCommitsTable() {
    await dyn.createTable({
        ProvisionedThroughput,
        TableName: COMMITS,
        AttributeDefinitions: [
            {AttributeName: 'repository', AttributeType: 'S'},
            {AttributeName: 'createdAt-sha', AttributeType: 'S'},
        ],
        KeySchema: [
            {AttributeName: 'repository', KeyType: 'HASH'},
            {AttributeName: 'createdAt-sha', KeyType: 'RANGE'},
        ]
    })
}
```

If you use a sortable timestamp string that will allow you to use the createdAt-sha concatenation as a sort key and use contains as a condition in the write like this:

```
async function putCommits() {
    await dc.put({
        TableName: COMMITS,
        Item: {
          repository: 'linux',
          createdAt-sha: Date.now() + '-6a13feb9c82803e2b815eca72fa7a9f5561d7861'
        },
        ConditionExpression:
          'attribute_not_exists(repository) and NOT contains("createdAt-sha", sha)'
    })
}
```

You can then query the table for the sorted commits by date.  Not sure the formatting on all this is correct, but that should be the general idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It didn't occur to me to use `contains` to enforce uniqueness. Thank you!